# What credentials to use during 'pod trunk push'?

Tags: cocoapods

I have a problem with authenticating my account during `pod trunk push` because I don't know what username or password I need to use. I have tried my email, as well as typical username which is connected to my Github profile with password, which is stored and was copied from my password manager. What is the biggest possibility I'm doing wrong?

[image: screenshot from my work]

I have tried different username and password scenarios but nothing was working.

Comment: I think the answer is in the error message.  Why not check the url.

Comment: I have already set up my Personal Access Token but still it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To publish a podspec to trunk, the podspec must reference a to public repos.

From https://github.com/Wannabe-games, "The organization has no public repos."

See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html if you want to work with private CocoaPods.

Comment: thx man, u were right because I didn;t know that